# Objective-C, AVFoundation Export movie with changed metadata

Tags: objective-c, xcode, video, avfoundation, transcoding

I want to export some video with custom creation date in metadata to mov file. The problem is, that I managed only to change one of dates stored in file. This is ffmpeg output of created video:

```
Metadata:
    major_brand     : qt  
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: qt  
    creation_time   : 2015-02-04 13:04:41
    comment         : EASTMAN KODAK COMPANY  KODAK CX7220 DIGITAL CAMERA
    comment-eng     : EASTMAN KODAK COMPANY  KODAK CX7220 DIGITAL CAMERA
    encoder         : Lavf55.12.100
    date            : 2004-01-01T00:00:00+0100
  Duration: 00:00:26.20, start: 0.092880, bitrate: 1506 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuvj420p, 320x240, 1430 kb/s, 14.92 fps, 15 tbr, 15360 tbn, 30 tbc
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2015-02-04 13:04:41
      handler_name    : Core Media Data Handler
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 11025 Hz, mono, fltp, 66 kb/s
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2015-02-04 13:04:41
      handler_name    : Core Media Data Handler
```

Only "date" property is correct, I would like to set the same also all other dates: creation_time and these dates in all streams.

This is more or less the code I use so far:

```
        AVAsset *asset = [AVAsset assetWithURL:fileURL];    // Asset przetwarzanego pliku wideo (Input)

        // Zbierz informacje o pliku
        NSString *fileDateString = [fileURL.lastPathComponent substringToIndex:19]; // Data wynikająca z nazwy pliku (NSString)
        NSDate *suggestedDate = [dateFormatter1 dateFromString:fileDateString];     // Data wynikająca z nazwy pliku (NSDate)

        NSString *oldLocationString = nil;  // Lokalizacja GPS zapisana w pliku
        NSDate *oldCreationDate = nil;      // Data utworzenia zapisana w pliku
        NSDate *oldModificationDate = nil;  // Data zmian zapisana w pliku

        // Wyciągnij informacje zapisane w pliku
        NSArray *metadata = asset.metadata; // Originalne informacje zapisane w pliku
        NSMutableArray *newMetadata = [metadata mutableCopy];   // Nowe zmodyfikowane informacje

        // Znajdź w oryginalnych informacjach wzmianki o datach i lokalizacji i usuń je z nowych informacji
        for (AVMutableMetadataItem *metadataItem in metadata) {
            NSString *commonKey = metadataItem.commonKey;
            NSString *stringValue = metadataItem.stringValue;
            NSDate *dateValue = metadataItem.dateValue;

            if ([commonKey isEqualToString:AVMetadataCommonKeyLocation] && stringValue) {
                oldLocationString = stringValue;
                [newMetadata removeObject:metadataItem];
            }
            else if ([commonKey isEqualToString:AVMetadataCommonKeyCreationDate] && dateValue) {
                oldCreationDate = dateValue;
                [newMetadata removeObject:metadataItem];
            }
            else if ([commonKey isEqualToString:AVMetadataCommonKeyLastModifiedDate] && dateValue) {
                oldModificationDate = dateValue;
                [newMetadata removeObject:metadataItem];
            }
        }

        // Wyznacz poprawną datę utworzenia na podstawie nazwy pliku lub dat zapisanych w oryginalnych informacjach
        NSDate *selectedDate = nil;
        if (suggestedDate) {
            selectedDate = suggestedDate;
        }
        else if (oldCreationDate) {
            selectedDate = oldCreationDate;
        }
        else if (oldModificationDate) {
            selectedDate = oldModificationDate;
        }

        // Wyznacz poprawną lokalizację na podstawie danych zapisanych w oryginalnych informacjach
        NSString *selectedLocation = nil;
        if (oldLocationString) {
            selectedLocation = oldLocationString;
        }

        // Dodaj do nowych informacji wyznaczoną datę utworzenia
        if (selectedDate) {
            NSString *newDataString = [dateFormatter5 stringFromDate:selectedDate];
            AVMutableMetadataItem *metaItem = [AVMutableMetadataItem metadataItem];
            metaItem.key = AVMetadataCommonKeyCreationDate;
            metaItem.keySpace = AVMetadataKeySpaceCommon;
            metaItem.value = newDataString;
            [newMetadata addObject:metaItem];
        }

        // Dodaj do nowych informacji wyznaczoną lokalizację
        if (oldLocationString) {
            AVMutableMetadataItem *metaItem = [AVMutableMetadataItem metadataItem];
            metaItem.key = AVMetadataCommonKeyLocation;
            metaItem.keySpace = AVMetadataKeySpaceCommon;
            metaItem.value = oldLocationString;
            [newMetadata addObject:metaItem];
        }

        // Ustal nową ścieżkę pliku wyjściowego
        NSString *dateString1 = [dateFormatter1 stringFromDate:selectedDate];
        NSString *fileExt = fileURL.pathExtension;
        NSString *newFileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ (%06lu)", dateString1, (unsigned long)index];
        NSString *newFilePath = [newLibraryPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:[fileURL.path substringFromIndex:libraryURL.path.length]];
        newFilePath = [[[newFilePath substringToIndex:newFilePath.length - newFilePath.lastPathComponent.length] stringByAppendingPathComponent:newFileName] stringByAppendingPathExtension:fileExt];
        NSString *newFileDir = [newFilePath substringToIndex:newFilePath.length - newFilePath.lastPathComponent.length];

        // Utwórz wymagane katalogi
        BOOL isDirectory;
        if (![fileManager fileExistsAtPath:newFileDir isDirectory:&isDirectory]) {
            [fileManager createDirectoryAtPath:newFileDir withIntermediateDirectories:YES attributes:nil error:nil];
        }

        // Wyeksportuj wideo z nowymi informacjami
        AVAssetExportSession *exportSession = [AVAssetExportSession exportSessionWithAsset:asset presetName:AVAssetExportPresetPassthrough];
        exportSession.metadata = newMetadata;
        exportSession.shouldOptimizeForNetworkUse = YES;
        exportSession.outputURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:newFilePath];
        exportSession.outputFileType = AVFileTypeQuickTimeMovie;


        dispatch_semaphore_t sema = dispatch_semaphore_create(0);
        [exportSession exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler:^{
            dispatch_semaphore_signal(sema);
        }];
        dispatch_semaphore_wait(sema, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);
```

Or different code, that basically do the same thing, but can access all streams (tracks), maybe someone can help with that

```
        // Creating the Asset Reader
        NSError *outError;
        AVAssetReader *assetReader = [AVAssetReader assetReaderWithAsset:asset error:&outError];
        BOOL success = (assetReader != nil);
        assert(success);

        // Creating the Asset Writer
        NSURL *outputURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:newFilePath];
        AVAssetWriter *assetWriter = [AVAssetWriter assetWriterWithURL:outputURL fileType:AVFileTypeQuickTimeMovie error:&outError];
        success = (assetWriter != nil);
        assert(success);


        // Setting Up the Asset Reader Outputs
        NSMutableArray *outputObjects = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:asset.tracks.count];
        for (AVAssetTrack *videoTrack in [asset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo]) {
            AVAssetReaderOutput *videoTrackOutput = [AVAssetReaderTrackOutput assetReaderTrackOutputWithTrack:videoTrack outputSettings:nil];
            if ([assetReader canAddOutput:videoTrackOutput]) {
                [assetReader addOutput:videoTrackOutput];
            }
            AVAssetWriterInput *assetVideoWriterInput = [AVAssetWriterInput assetWriterInputWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo outputSettings:nil];
            if ([assetWriter canAddInput:assetVideoWriterInput]) {
                [assetWriter addInput:assetVideoWriterInput];
            }
            AVAssetTrack *videoAssetTrack = videoTrack;
            assetVideoWriterInput.transform = videoAssetTrack.preferredTransform;

            [outputObjects addObject:@{@"Output" : videoTrackOutput, @"Input" : assetVideoWriterInput}];
        }
        for (AVAssetTrack *audioTrack in [asset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio]) {
            AVAssetReaderOutput *audioTrackOutput = [AVAssetReaderTrackOutput assetReaderTrackOutputWithTrack:audioTrack outputSettings:nil];
            if ([assetReader canAddOutput:audioTrackOutput]) {
                [assetReader addOutput:audioTrackOutput];
            }
            AVAssetWriterInput *assetAudioWriterInput = [AVAssetWriterInput assetWriterInputWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio outputSettings:nil];
            if ([assetWriter canAddInput:assetAudioWriterInput]) {
                [assetWriter addInput:assetAudioWriterInput];
            }
            AVAssetTrack *videoAssetTrack = audioTrack;
            assetAudioWriterInput.transform = videoAssetTrack.preferredTransform;

            [outputObjects addObject:@{@"Output" : audioTrackOutput, @"Input" : assetAudioWriterInput}];
        }

        // Setup metadata
        assetWriter.metadata = newMetadata;

        // Writing Media Data
        [assetWriter startWriting];
        [assetWriter startSessionAtSourceTime:kCMTimeZero];
        [assetReader startReading];

        dispatch_semaphore_t sema1 = dispatch_semaphore_create(0);
        __block NSUInteger numberOfOutputs = outputObjects.count;
        for (NSDictionary *outputObjectDictionary in outputObjects) {
            AVAssetWriterInput *assetWriterInput = outputObjectDictionary[@"Input"];
            AVAssetReaderOutput *assetReaderOutput = outputObjectDictionary[@"Output"];
            [assetWriterInput requestMediaDataWhenReadyOnQueue:dispatch_queue_create(nil, nil) usingBlock:^{
                while ([assetWriterInput isReadyForMoreMediaData]) {
                    CMSampleBufferRef nextSampleBuffer = [assetReaderOutput copyNextSampleBuffer];
                    if (nextSampleBuffer) {
                        [assetWriterInput appendSampleBuffer:nextSampleBuffer];
                        CFRelease(nextSampleBuffer);
                        nextSampleBuffer = nil;
                    }
                    else {
                        [assetWriterInput markAsFinished];
                        if (--numberOfOutputs == 0) {
                            dispatch_semaphore_signal(sema1);
                        }
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }];
        }
        dispatch_semaphore_wait(sema1, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);

        dispatch_semaphore_t sema2 = dispatch_semaphore_create(0);
        [assetWriter finishWritingWithCompletionHandler:^{
            NSLog(@"DONE");
            dispatch_semaphore_signal(sema2);
        }];
        dispatch_semaphore_wait(sema2, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);
```

Please help

Comment: Were you ever able to get this figured out?